# UDF for If statement with multiple components

Tags: vba, function, excel, if-statement

I am trying to create a function (=StatusExpected) that will return pass/fail after evaluating multiple components. To be specific, four components (Size, Liquidity, Qualification, Exception) return "Pass/Fail".  If all four return "Pass", I would like StatusExpected="Pass". If one or more of these components returns "Fail", I would like StatusExpected="Fail".

StatusExpected populates I7:I506, and the four variables populate each row, straight across in J,AB,AF,AP respectively. I did not think this should matter however, as I am looking for a function with four inputs.

Below is what I have that isn't working:

```
Function StatusExpected(Size As String, Liquidity As String, Qualified As String, Exception As String)
    Range("A1").Select.Activate
    If Size = "Pass" And Liquidity = "Pass" And Qualified = "Pass" And Exception = "Pass" Then
        StatusExpected = "Pass"
    Else
        StatusExpected = "Fail"
    End If
End Function
```

If you could, please also reply with whether you need to activate a cell, or if you need to define variables.  Please start the code from the beginning with the Function line, as if nothing else exists and provide me with anything that could help me in addition to my question, as well as best practices for clarity.

Comment: I don't believe `.Select.Activate` is valid syntax and `Activate` or `Select` are almost never required.  Most operations can be completed without the code (which comes at a performance penalty).

Comment: Function StatusExpected(Size As String, Liquidity As String, Qualified As String, Exception As String)
If Size = "Pass" And Liquidity = "Pass" And Qualified = "Pass" And Exception = "Pass" Then
    StatusExpected = "Pass"
Else
    StatusExpected = "Fail"
End If
End Function

still does not work for me
Still does not work for me, do you know why this could be failing? Preemptively "Pass" and "Fail" always use the same casing
Else
    StatusExpected = "Fail"
End If
End Function

Comment: And when I type =StatusExpected in "I" It highlights a whole range of cells down to 506

Comment: What formula are you using in cell J7?

Answer (score 0):

To begin:

```
.Select.Activate
```

Is not valid syntax.  It should be one or the other.  In most cases, however, this is an unnecessary operation which hinders performance (typically not noticeable for small operations, but in the interest of good coding practice you should avoid using `.Select` and `.Activate`)

So your function:

```
Function StatusExpected(Size As String, Liquidity As String, Qualified As String, Exception As String)
    If Size = "Pass" And Liquidity = "Pass" And Qualified = "Pass" And Exception = "Pass" Then
        StatusExpected = "Pass"
    Else
        StatusExpected = "Fail"
    End If
End Function
```

Works for me (Excel 2013).

One thing I did notice is that this function is case sensitive.  Consider the following data in columns J, AB, AF, AP:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass |
+------+------+------+------+
| PASS | PASS | PASS | PASS |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Your function would return `Pass` for the first row, but would return `Fail` for the second row because text comparisons are, by default, case sensitive.

One way to change that is to add the `Option Compare Text` line to the top of your code, which will make text comparisons case insensitive.  So if you did this:

```
Option Compare Text

Function StatusExpected(Size As String, Liquidity As String, Qualified As String, Exception As String)
    If Size = "Pass" And Liquidity = "Pass" And Qualified = "Pass" And Exception = "Pass" Then
        StatusExpected = "Pass"
    Else
        StatusExpected = "Fail"
    End If
End Function
```

The data set above would return `Pass` in both instances.

Comment: Thank you for the case heads-up.  I am using 2010, and that function will not work for me.  Any reason come to mind why this would be?

Comment: @IanK try to verify if the function is actually invoked: put a breakpoint on a line of code inside, then refresh one of the cells in your worksheet. Is it invoked?

Comment: Great! Would you share your solution then? :)

Comment: It was the solution aboive that Soulfire provided